# Add values to new column based on values of existing column efficiently with Pandas

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

I  am using the script below in order to create a new Dataframe column that will have values depending on the REGEX match with values from an existing column:

```
import pandas as pd 

#Creation of the dataframe
data = [['Value One', 10], ['Value Six', 15],['Value Six', 25], ['Value * Three', 14],['Other', 14]] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ColumnA', 'columnB'])

#Create new column with the values depending on the values of an existing column 
df.loc[df['ColumnA'].str.match("Value One|Value Two|Value \* Three"),'Category'] = 'One'
df.loc[df['ColumnA'].str.match("Value Four|Value Six|Value \* Five"),'Category'] = 'Two'

#Replace the nulls - the ones that didn't have a match above - with a value
df.Category.fillna('Not Specified', inplace=True)
```

The code works fine but my target is to optimise it and make it work for more complex scenarios. I want to avoid having many rows of `df.loc`s and I was wondering whether there is a way to automate this using for example a dictionary.

- Firstly, having different lists for the values that need to be matched (`str.match` can be replaced with `str.contains` I guess in this case with a regex inside the parenthesis)
- Secondly, having different lists for the values that will be added in the new column
- Thirdly, (that is what I am thinking but feel free to come with any solution for the overall) a loop that will use the df.loc and add the lists above. That might require a creation of dictionary with the two types of lists I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is useful or if you already know this but you could use vectorize

```py
import numpy as np

def regexr(x):
    if x.match("Value One|Value Two|Value \* Three"):
        return "one"
    elif x.match("Value Four|Value Six|Value \* Five"):
        return "Two"
    else:
        return "Unspecified"

regexr = np.vectorize(regexr)

df['columnA'].values = regexr(df['columnA'].values)
```